# Find link inside of source and copy whole link webclient

Tags: c#, webclient

So i'm using c# and I want to grab a single link that starts with a set domain from a page.

Example the link i want to grab is https://example.com/yikes/###### with the '#' being a random string.

Note this is inside a large html file with multiple links inside of it. Some of the links also contain https://example.com/ but none contain https://example.com/yikes/ but this one.

Also it is in a iFrame. I don't know if that is useful information. or not.

The html looks something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<a href="https://example.com">This is a link</a>
<a href="https://example.com/ooof">This is also link</a>
<iframe src="https://example.com/ooof"></iframe>
<iframe src="https://example.com/yikes/138fskg"></iframe>
<iframe src="https://example.com/biggie"></iframe>


</body>
</html>
```

Here is about as far as I could get myself with this

```
string videoLink = wc.DownloadString(link);
bool contain = videoLink.Contains("https://example.com/yikes/");
if (contain == true)
{ 
      //Copy whole link
}
```

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you want to have the links that starts with `"https://example.com/yikes/"`.

```
string[] videoLinks = new string[5]
{
"<iframe src='https://example.com/ooof'></iframe>",
"<iframe src='https://example.com/yikes/138fskg'></iframe>",
"<iframe src='https://example.com/biggie'></iframe>",
"<iframe src='https://example.com/yikes/138fskg/1231'></iframe>",
"<iframe src='https://example.com/yikes/138fskg/12314531'></iframe>",
};
string link = "https://example.com/yikes/";

var matchedValues = videoLinks.Where(v => v.Contains(link));
foreach (var item in matchedValues)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Output:

```
<iframe src='https://example.com/yikes/138fskg'></iframe>
<iframe src='https://example.com/yikes/138fskg/1231'></iframe>
<iframe src='https://example.com/yikes/138fskg/12314531'></iframe>
```

Comment: I have to find it inside the 'string videoLink = wc.DownloadString(link);' not in a set array as the html string changes multiple times a day